# cakePHP email plugin - problems configuring it to my CakePHP installation

Tags: plugins, cakephp-1.3, email, gmail-imap

I'm trying to add this email plugin to my **CakePHP v1.3.3** installation, but I'm having newbie problems.

Here's the plugin: [GitHub SourceCode](https://github.com/kvz/cakephp-emails-plugin)

I tried to follow the fairly clear example but I'm not sure what to put for some of the parameters for the datasource connection.

I have a Gmail account I want to connect to via IMAP. Here's my database code. I'm not sure what to put for 'connect' and 'datasource'.

```
public $emailCardOrder = array(
    'datasource' => 'Emails.Imap',
    'server' => 'imap.gmail.com',
    'connect' => 'imap/tls/novalidate-cert',
    'username' => 'abcd@gmail.com',
    'password' => '#######',
    'port' => '993',
    'ssl' => true,
    'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
    'error_handler' => 'php',
    'auto_mark_as' => array(
        'Seen',
        // 'Answered',
        // 'Flagged',
        // 'Deleted',
        // 'Draft',
    ),
);
```

The error I get is: 
`PHP Fatal error:  ConnectionManager::loadDataSource - Unable to import DataSource class Emails.ImapSource in /repos/intranet/trunk/cake/libs/model/connection_manager.php on line 185`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your datasource to whatever your datasource name is. By default it is not Emails.Imap. The plugin is called CakePHP-Email-Plugin, so it should be 'CakePHP-Email-Plugin.ImapSource'.

```
public $emailCardOrder = array(
    'datasource' => 'CakePHP-Email-Plugin.ImapSource',
    'server' => 'imap.gmail.com',
    'connect' => 'imap/tls/novalidate-cert',
    'username' => 'abcd@gmail.com',
    'password' => '#######',
    'port' => '993',
    'ssl' => true,
    'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
    'error_handler' => 'php',
    'auto_mark_as' => array(
        'Seen' //,
        // 'Answered',
        // 'Flagged',
        // 'Deleted',
        // 'Draft',
    ),
```

);

Two years, better late than never!

Answer (score 1):

Be carefully do You have the file imap_source.php really in the right path: `app/plugins/emails/` !
May be these files are in subdir when You uzip it with WinZip ;-)

So, second, I must change code in function `connect` to get finaly the string for connection with name of folder in email box like this:
`{<server_name_or_ip>:<port><connect_string>}<folder_name>`

for example:
    {server.name.cz:143/imap/notls}INBOX

May be this is speciality of windows imap servers like IceWarp or MS Exchange server.

You can control the success of connection in the line 504 in file imap_source.php

--
Mareg

Answer (score 0):

Here is my set up for this plugin

i put datasource at
/app/models/datasource/imap_source.php

in database.php added this variable

```
var $emailTicket = array(
        'datasource' => 'imap',
        'server' => 'imap.gmail.com',
        //'connect' => 'imap/tls/novalidate-cert', //comment it out
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => '*******',
        'port' => '993',
        'ssl' => true,
        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
        'error_handler' => 'php',
        'auto_mark_as' => array(
            'Seen',
            // 'Answered',
            // 'Flagged',
            // 'Deleted',
            // 'Draft',
        )
    );
```

and in my model

```
var $useDbConfig = 'emailTicket';
```

This works fine, untill you try to fetch attachments

for fetching attachments i uncommented these two lines and commented one other line for flag is_attachment

```
protected function _awesomePart($Part, $uid) {
    if (!($Part->format = @$this->encodingTypes[$Part->type])) {
        $Part->format = $this->encodingTypes[0];
    }

    if (!($Part->datatype = @$this->dataTypes[$Part->type])) {
        $Part->datatype = $this->dataTypes[0];
    }

    $Part->mimeType = strtolower($Part->datatype . '/' . $Part->subtype);

    $Part->is_attachment = false;
    $Part->filename      = '';
    $Part->name          = '';
    $Part->uid           = $uid;

    if ($Part->ifdparameters) {
        foreach ($Part->dparameters as $Object) {
            if (strtolower($Object->attribute) === 'filename') {
                #$Part->is_attachment = true; //uncomment this line
                $Part->filename      = $Object->value;
            }
        }
    }

    if ($Part->ifparameters) {
        foreach ($Part->parameters as $Object) {
            if (strtolower($Object->attribute) === 'name') {
                #$Part->is_attachment = true; //uncomment this line
                $Part->name          = $Object->value;
            }
        }
    }

    if (false !== strpos($Part->path, '.')) {
        $Part->is_attachment = true; //comment this line
    }

    return $Part;
}
```

hope this works for you